# changing sql statement to eloquent query

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

So I have an SQL statement as such;

```
AND created_at BETWEEN '20190601' and '20190630'
```

How do I change this to an eloquent query? Or is it better to just use a db:raw query?

All inputs are very much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: use whereBetween

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$yourQuery->whereBetween('created_at', ['20190601', '20190630']);
```

Read more at whereBetween section in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 2):

As you are comparing dates, then do this:

```
$fromDate = '20190601';
$toDate = '20190630';
$yourquery->whereBetween('created_at', array($fromDate->toDateTimeString(), $toDate->toDateTimeString()) )->get();
```

Comment: My Pleasure @UdhayanNair

Comment: accept the answer if its works for you @UdhayanNair.